# How to wrap a void* pointer into a TCL Object

Tags: c, tcl

I'm trying to save a void* pointer (or any pointer) into a tcl Object so I can retrieve it later. I saw SWIG convert it to a string with some encoding and later decode it. But in order to make it more efficient, I want to directly get the pointer in and out of the tcl obj. Something like a Tcl_GetPointerFromObj(). Is there anyway to do it? Do I need to dig into the Tcl_Obj structure and do some dirty work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest reading [this page on the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1089) which is on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tcl_RegisterObjType to create a new Tcl object type that holds a void pointer.  This allows you to extend Tcl so that Tcl_ObjType can be used to store (in your case) void* and to be able to write Tcl_GetPointerfromObj.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Tcl API: `Tcl_GetWideIntFromObj()`, though I think storing pointers in Tcl is the first step toward madness....

Comment: To use a big int seems too dangerous, I won't risk it... I want to have both flexibility and speed, so that's the only way.